# Margin not displaying properly

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm creating my personal website build on wordpress and now I'm remaking template. After whole day of doing css, html and php...and looking for a lot of things of internet, I encountred for a lot of people known problem.

Somewhere in my site, some element is giving me margin which i don't want. You can see it on the picture below:

[image]

I know the rules of this website, to give code and you will try to help me, but now, I don't know where is the problem. So if someone with bigger experience and little bit of time can look at my page, I would be really thankfull.

My site si [svrcek.webfix.sk](http://svrcek.webfix.sk)

Comment: which margin is that both side?

Comment: it's margin between div with id main and nav with id site-navigation

Comment: You should really accept the answer from @lee_gladding most of the other answers on here are hacks and can prove inconsistent between various browsers. His answer is the real cause.

Comment: yes, now i see it as the best...when i was writing that i will accept answer guillaume the post from lee was not here...:) whanks for advice

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You front slider has a `<p>` in it that has margin.

delete this node and the space goes.

As it is empty do you need it? and if so can you add styling to it?

Comment: You just beat me to this! I see a pair of empty <p> tags at the bottom of your front slider class that is causing this issue.

Comment: yes now i see it...it's premade slider so i will look to the code to solve it :) thanks

Comment: Yes, it's a stray end tag `</p>` (there are two in the source, at lines 90 and 91) that produces empty `P` element which has default 16px top margin which collapses out of the `.front-slider` and the main wrapper. Probably you copied some redundant code by adding a slider. As a quick-and-dirty fix, try just `.front-slider p { display: none; }`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.front-slider` element is causing the gap. Add a `position:absolute` to fix it. (If it's not the markup of the slider, you could also remove the redundant `<p>` which initially is causing the problem.)

To have really clean code, you should remove all absolute positioning from the child elements and just position the `.front-slider` wrapper accordingly. Also it seems like your green navigation buttons don't work. Probably there is an option to position and style the `soliloquy-next` and `soliloquy-prev` buttons which seem a but redundant at the moment.

Comment: thanks, it worked, but also the help from @Guillaume Lehezee and she was first so I will give answer accept to her, thanks very much :)

Comment: @M.Svrcek technically I was 30 seconds earlier than her;) You can hover over the timestamp to see the exact posting time but feel free to give the vote to anyone whom you like

Comment: yes you are right...but after all i didn't gave her that vote...i gave it to lee_glading :) i hope you agree with me :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you have this margin, but this CSS will fix that :

```
.front-slider {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, In 4min I will give you answe accept because you have been first to answer my question :) thanks once again :)

Comment: thanks for the answer accept ! but im still waiting for it :'(